# не определяется Faye

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gems, coffeescript

пишу простой чат в реальном времени, подключил гем "faye", чтобы сообщения сразу отображались без перезагрузки страницы. при отправке сообщения faye не определяется, поэтому необходимо перезагружать страницу, чтобы увидеть сообщения, отправленные другим человеком

**`messages_controller.rb`**

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        if current_user
            @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
            if @message.save
                flash[:success] = 'Ура, отправилось! :)'
            else
                flash[:error] = 'Ошибка :('
            end
            format.html {redirect_to root_path}
            format.js
        else
            format.html {redirect_to root_path}
            format.js {render nothing: true}
        end
    end
end
```

**`application.js`**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require faye
//= require messages
```

**`messages.coffee`**

```
window.client = new Faye.Client('/faye')

jQuery ->
    $('#new_message').submit ->
        $(this).find("input[type='submit']").val('Отправляем...').prop('disabled', true)
    try
        client.unsubscribe('/messages')
    catch
        console?.log "Can't unsubscribe"

    client.subscribe '/messages', (payload) ->
        $('#messages').find('.media-list').prepend(payload.message) if payload.message
```

**`create.js.erb`**

```
publisher = client.publish('/messages', {
    message: '<%= j render @message %>'
});

publisher.callback(function() {
    $("#message_body").val('');
    $("#new_message").find("input[type='submit']").val('Отправить').prop('disabled', false)
});

publisher.errback(function() {
    alert('Ошибочка :(');
});
```

https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/chatclone.git исходный код

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37941/discussion-on-question-by-alexnikolaev94---faye).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@D-side, @cheops как оказалось, проблема была таки с **Csrf Protection**. по какой-то причине он блокировал Faye, и эта проблема существует как в `faye 2.0.0`, так и в `faye 2.0.1`. Внедрение `csrf_protection` было проведено согласно [актуальной документации](http://faye.jcoglan.com/security/csrf.html), но причины, по которой `faye` не мог подписаться на канал из-за `csrf_protection`, не было обнаружено, так что обсуждение вопроса переместилось [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389909/conflict-between-faye-and-csrf-protection). По теме - убрал csrf_protection, и заработало.

Comment: "**Example: Rails**" <- ну ни фига себе ничего .-.

Comment: @D-side, я имел в виду, что все было сделано согласно документации, и поэтому не должно было возникнуть проблем - но они были. я перечитал документацию - все было правильно. но почему-то именно из-за `csrf_protection` `faye` не мог подписаться на канал. возможно, сменилась какая-нибудь библиотека в самом геме :( прошу прощения, что неточно выразился

Comment: Хм... да, нашёл расширение, в прошлый раз проморгал. А делать там `pry` и смотреть, что происходит, пробовали?

Comment: @D-side, нет, пробовали делать даунгрейд до старых версий, не помогло(

Comment: Так надо открыть отладчиком CSRF-проверялку, когда устанавливается соединение, и проверить, есть ли там токен.